# How to center the text vertically with richtextbox?

Tags: c#, wpf

Follow code:

The idea is to center the text horizontally and vertically.

The code below, the text is centered horizontally.

```
<RichTextBox 
    x:Name="richtextbox" 
    Height="285"
    Width="341"
    Margin="10,53,0,0" 
    VerticalAlignment="Top" 
    FontSize="14" 
    VerticalContentAlignment="Center" 
    HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" 
    UseLayoutRounding="False" 
    VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
    Block.TextAlignment="Center"
    Grid.ColumnSpan="2" 
    HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
    TextChanged="richtextbox_TextChanged" 
    BorderThickness="1">
    <FlowDocument>
        <Paragraph>
            This is flow content and you can
            <Bold>edit me!</Bold>
        </Paragraph>
    </FlowDocument>
</RichTextBox>
```

Result:

[image]

With the `richtextbox` tool you can not center the text vertically. Is there anyway to center text in C#? Implementing C# code to center richtextbox, is it possible?

Maybe I can work to center it with `richtextbox.BorderThickness = new Thickness (1, 1, 1, 1);`, changing the value of `top`.

Any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">                    
<Grid Height="285" Background="White" >
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1" MaxHeight="285" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <RichTextBox  
        x:Name="richtextbox" 
        Width="341"
        VerticalAlignment="Top" 
        FontSize="14" 
        VerticalContentAlignment="Center" 
        HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" 
        UseLayoutRounding="False" 
        VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
        Block.TextAlignment="Center"
        Grid.ColumnSpan="2" 
        HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
        BorderThickness="0">
        <FlowDocument>       

            <Paragraph>
                This is flow content and you can
                <Bold>edit me!</Bold>
            </Paragraph>
        </FlowDocument>
    </RichTextBox>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
</Border>
```

probably not ideal, but it will look the same.

Comment: Does it work with the `VerticalScrollBarVisibility` property?

Comment: It doesn't work cleanly, you need to hardcode the `MaxHeight`  I've updated the answer

Comment: The `richtextbox_TextChanged` event is triggered several times, why?

Comment: You know how I can handle this?

Comment: @MatheusMiranda it's getting triggered every time you type