# Event "TextChanged" is fired multiple times

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox

I asked a question here how to centralize richtextbox vertically: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49011263/how-to-center-the-text-vertically-with-richtextbox)

Follow code:

**XAML:**

```
<Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Margin="10,51,385,14.2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
            <Grid x:Name="Grid_Principal" Height="285" Background="Black" >
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <ScrollViewer x:Name="scrollviewer" Grid.Row="1" MaxHeight="285" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Margin="10,0.4,0.4,0.2">
                    <RichTextBox
                        x:Name="richtextbox" 
                        Width="332.4"
                        VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                        FontSize="14" 
                        VerticalContentAlignment="Center" 
                        HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" 
                        UseLayoutRounding="False" 
                        VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
                        Block.TextAlignment="Center"
                        Grid.ColumnSpan="2" 
                        HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                        BorderThickness="0" 
                        Background="{x:Null}" 
                        Foreground="White" 
                        TextChanged="Richtextbox_TextChanged">
                        <FlowDocument>
                            <Paragraph>
                                This is flow content and you can
                                <Bold>edit me!</Bold>
                            </Paragraph>
                        </FlowDocument>
                    </RichTextBox>
                </ScrollViewer>
            </Grid>
        </Border>
```

**C#:**

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    richtextbox.AppendText("Hello world, I'm writing in C#");
}

private void Richtextbox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
   //This event is fired multiple times
}
```

The `TextChanged` event is fired several times, done in debugger mode, fired here 6 times.

I want to call a function when the text is changed, any solution?

Comment: `TextChanged` fires everytime the text inside the textbox changes (if you type "hello", it'll be fired 5 times, one per char typed); that's how it works.

Comment: @JoshPart This I know, please see my post, I edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As has been already said, the text changes on every keystroke and so your event fires each time.

You actually have to decide what behavior you want. Some things I usually do:

Want "Enter" key to confirm text, then (Pseudocode):

```
KeyDown="Richtextbox_TextChanged"> (XAML)
if (e.Key.Equals(Key.Return)) doWhatYouWannaDo(); (CODE)
```

Want focus change to confirm text:

```
LostFocus="Richtextbox_TextChanged"> (XAML), 
doWhatYouWannaDo(); (CODE)
```

where CODE is to be placed inside the body of Richtextbox_TextChanged() or however you want to name it.

**Edit:** What you could also do is validate the text after some time has passed (i.e. in a timer event). But I don't like that one because it is somehow interacting with the user nondeterministically.

Comment: LostFocus event helped me.